# SQLPlus conditional execution with variable from query

Tags: batch-file, sqlplus, conditional-statements

I have a batch file which has many steps in it that will get executed one by one.

However, to be able to make it more flexible, I want to include a condition check in `SQLPlus`.

Something like, to get the conditional variables' value from a query first and store is in say `v_variable`. Then use it for some checks like

```
IF v_variable = 'Y' THEN
--DO SOME DDL
ELSE
--DO OTHER DDL
END IF
```

I have to repeat this block in many places in the batch file and I can't do it through a PL/SQL somehow.

I am trying to use this `COLUMN` command in `SQLPlus` but somehow not getting the variable value to get saved.

```
COLUMN VARIABLE1 NEW_VALUE V_VARIABLE1

SELECT PARAM_VAL AS VARIABLE1 FROM TABLE_T WHERE PARAM_TYPE =  'XYZ'; 
-- This query will only throw one record.

DEFINE V_VARIABLE1
```

Is that absolutely wrong? What do we do to see if the `V_VARIABLE1` is getting the value coming from the query?

And even after I get it right I am clueless on the `IF-ELSE` part. Can anybody help here? I am interested in solution that works for SQLPlus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sql*plus doesn't support flow control natively, so anything you can do here would fall somewhere between "workaround" and "hack". Some of possible options are:

1. Use PL/SQL block and run your DDL as dynamic SQL via `execute
   immediate` or `dbms_utility.execute_ddl_statement`. Full access to
   PL/SQL features, so most flexible in terms of flow control and
   statement building, however harder to manage if you're deploying
   something large.
2. Write a script file per if/else branch, get its name with something
   like column/query trick you provided in your post, run it with
   something like `@&scriptname`.
3. Use substitution variables that, when used properly, will comment
   out some parts of your script. You can use Tanel Poder's snapper
   utility [script](http://blog.tanelpoder.com/files/scripts/snapper.sql) as example; notice `&_IF_` substitution
   variables there.
4. You can *embed* child script into parent script's pl/sql block. Like
   this:

--

```
21:21:23 SQL> ho cat run.sql
begin
case '&1.' when 'A' then
@script_a
when 'B' then
@script_b
else
null;
end case;
end;
/

21:21:26 SQL> ho cat script_a.sql
dbms_output.put_line('this is a');

21:21:30 SQL> ho cat script_b.sql
dbms_output.put_line('this is b');

21:21:34 SQL> @run
Enter value for 1: A
this is a

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
21:21:37 SQL> @run B
this is b

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Now even I feel that SQLPlus is not gonna suffice. I have moved my code to a PL/SQL block.

Comment: @Neels just FYI - you might want to take a look at conditional compilation either http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#BABIHIHF

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with SQLPlus. I am going to assume that you can redirect the output of your select command to a temp file. Assuming you only selected one column in 1 record you can then do something like this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR /v "(" YourTempFile.txt) DO SET YourVariable=%%A
```

"tokens=*" is optional. It will remove leading spaces and save the rest of the string including spaces. May not be relevant depending on your data.

You may not need the 'FINDSTR /V "(" and the trailing ' either. I am assuming the output of SQLPlus will be similar to SQL and this would exclude the number of rows processed that gets reported by SQL. Anything is possible. If you can't make this work, post the contents of the temp file and we can make the necessary modifications.